# How to convert pngs or gifs to APNG format in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want to generate apng from pngs or gifs. I have gone through with APNGKit but didn't find any help.

Thanks!

Comment: Will you please add some of your code that you tried.

Comment: I want to make it from scratch. don't have code

Comment: I checked this..but didn't find https://github.com/onevcat/APNGKit